# Display image inside a email message

Tags: joomla-3.x, emails, images

Hi is it possible to add images inline to notification emails that get sent from joomla?

Tried to just add a < img src="URL-TO-IMAGE" > to the email message strings in the language (.ini) files.

But when the email is sent this only shows up as a link to the image and not shown inline.

Comment: Language .ini files are not the place for that.

Comment: Are you giving absolute url or relative to your website? And how you are editing the email message?

Comment: I gave  absolute url like this http://www.example.com/images/image.png. I use the language override in Language manager to edit my email messages. Also tried to edit it directly in the language files but the result was the same. So I guess this has to be done in another way?